# Magento 1.9, 302 redirects

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, catalog-url-rewrite

In my Magento 1.9 site, I have made a category page to redirect to the product page. I have category A and it contains a product B. Now when from menu link if one clicks on category A name, it will be redirected to product B. Here, the problem is, it is showing that product B has multiple canonical URLs. I am failing to understand, why this is happening and a way to solve it.

Comment: redirect is working or not?

Comment: Can you tell me what you are pointing here as Canonical URLs?

Comment: redirect is working
I saw two canonical tags in page source, one was the product url and another was its link formed with category.